# Display image file using C programming

Tags: c, libpng

I want to read and display a png image using c programming. Please suggest some ways. Is it possible to use libPng library for displaying image ?

Comment: you didn't mention the OS

Comment: BTW, the simplest (and the ugliest) way is to call external viewer with your file (something like `system()` or `execl()`).

Answer (score 3):

libPng will only decode the image into an RGBA-array for you. To then display the image you could use OpenGL or an OS-dependendent graphics-library.

**EDIT**: Since you say you are using windows:

On Windows you have many library choices: I suggest you start with SDL, you can start by showing your image like this: http://www.sdltutorials.com/Data/Posts/105/ss1.jpg  and then continue building your application from there. There are many tutorials on SDL (see here: http://www.sdltutorials.com/tutorials). The JPG was from this one: http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-coordinates-and-blitting

Comment: okay. Thank you. So I am developing in windows machine. So I need to find some libraries that will help in displaying the image right?. Does ImageMagick fall into such category?

Comment: Also what i did is using zint and libpng i developed barcode images. Now i want to display the images. So my concern is how to do the display in C language

Comment: ImageMagick is a program, what you need is a library so that you can develop your own program instead of using ImageMagick. I edited my answer!